# Matlab/Octave-type functionality in Java - where to look

Tags: java, matlab, octave

I want to use some image processing methods for which source code is commonly available in Matlab, and implement then in Java. There's no funding for Matlab builder JA. Can anyone advise on a Java API that is meant to deliver Matlab/Octave type functionality? If not is there another strategy I should consider. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could post some of the functions you're looking to duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

An option might be to run the available Matlab code by calling the actual Matlab-functions from Java. This *JMI interface* has been an [undocumented feature](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/jmi-java-to-matlab-interface/) of Matlab for over a decade, so it's probably quite stable. There's also [matlabcontrol - A Java API to interact with MATLAB](http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/wiki/JMI).

The Matlab Builder JA would not compile your Matlab code into Java. It generates a Java interface for calling the Matlab functions and passing data - but runs the actual Matlab code in a Matlab runtime environment.